# Existence of a certain polynomial on $\mathbb P_k^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Let $k$ be an infinite field.
Let $X\subseteq\mathbb P_k^n$ be a projective subvariety.
Let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$.
Mumford and Oda’s *Algebraic Geometry II* says (in the paragraph following Definition 7.7.3 (on page 258 of [its draft](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwio8LHY65H0AhXHA4gKHe7vBqwQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.dam.brown.edu%2Fpeople%2Fmumford%2Falg_geom%2Fpapers%2FAGII.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2Wt9E2O8eG4N23R8OBXyRm))) that

> Now take a homogeneous polynomial $F$ endowed with the following properties:
>
> a) $X\not\subseteq V(F)$ and the effective Cartier divisor $H=\operatorname{Tr}_X(V(F))$ is reduced and irreducible,
>
> b) no component $D_j$ of $\operatorname{Supp} D$ is contained in $V (F )$.
>
> It can be shown that such an $F$ exists (in fact, in the affine space of all $F$’s, any $F$ outside a proper union of subvarieties will have these properties).

I can’t understand why such an $F$ exists.

I think “the affine space of all $F$’s” is the affine open $X_F$ of $X$ defined by $F$.
Then the property (b) for example says that $X_F\cap D_j\ne\emptyset$ for all $j$, but how can we do that?
I can’t get what “an $F$ outside a proper union of subvarieties” means.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up Bertini's theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also would like to know a more simple proof.